# Can't program PIC12

Tags: pic

I am trying to program PIC12 with a JDM and Tait programmer. Everything is OK in the first programming but I can't program PIC again. When I connect it to the programmer WinPICPgm is not able to recognize it and even is not able to recognize the programmer. I used programmer test in the Programmer Selection/Configuration window and found that when I attach PIC to the programmer and power it on DataOut does not changes by changing DataIn (It changes correctly while PIC is not connected or powered). I tested PIC12F675, PIC12F629 and PIC12F683. Note that my program uses internal oscillator, disables MCLR function and uses it as input, enables GP1 and GP2 pull-ups, uses GP1 and GP2 interrupt on change. I have not this problem with another code that does not enables pull-ups and interrupts on GP1 and GP2. Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Get a proper programmer, such as a PICkit 3.

Comment: OK. I bought a PICkit3 and waiting for delivery.

Comment: It also has the advantage of working as a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to program PIC12 with a JDM and Tait programmer ...
> Note that my program uses internal oscillator, disables MCLR function ...

It should be no surprise that this doesn't work.  You used a crappy programmer that cuts corners at the expense of robustness, plays fast and loose with the programming spec, and then gave it a difficult corner case.  You should be glad it managed to correctly program other things.

Comment: OK. I bought a PICkit3 and waiting for delivery.